# Issue unit testing this function in node with node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, fetch

I'm trying to unit test this function.... following the documentation.

Any ideas why i'm getting this error? According to the documentation we can see it being called this way... What am I missing. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks

Thankx

```js
async function isValid(pair) {
    const path = process.env.PATH;
    const query = '/check';
    const requestOptions = ccyServiceRequestOptions(pair);
    try {
        const response = await fetch(path + query, requestOptions);
        const json = await response.json();
        return json.result.pair === pair;
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof TypeError) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            log.error(err);
            throw err;
        }
    }
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
jest.mock('node-fetch');

const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const {Response} = jest.requireActual('node-fetch');


beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks()
})


it('should call with valid url', async () => {
        const pair = 'EURUSD';
        fetch.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(new Response({})));

        await ccyPairIsValid(pair);

        expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(fetch.mock.calls[0][0]).toHaveBeenCalledWith(process.env.PATH + '/check');
    })
```

```js
Error: expect(received).toHaveBeenCalledWith(...expected)

Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Received has type:  string
Received has value: "http://localhost:8000/check"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling fetch with two arguments, if you don’t care about your requestOptions argument then you can use `expect.anything()`